# How to add a new meta key and assign timestamp to posts

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, meta-query, timestamp

I've been trying to look for a way to create a loop in my website and show posts being read/watched but have not found anything.

The only way I can accomplish this would be to create a new meta key (custom field) and assign  timestamp as value, that way I can create a loop and use its value to list posts that are being watched within a time range, say 5 minutes.

The issue is that I am very very new to wordpress and i dont know how to do this T_T

Answer (score 1):

A very simplistic method of achieving this would be as follows;

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'recently_read');
function recently_read(){

    global $post;

    //only run this function for the posts post_type
    if ( !is_single() ) 
        return;

    //get the current time in the format of: 2013-02-22 11:55:51 
    $timestamp = current_time('mysql'); 

    //add the $timestamp variable to the meta_key for this post
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'reading_this', $timestamp);


}
```

Note: The above function goes into your theme `functions.php` file and is hooked onto the `template_redirect` action which is fired just before displaying the page to the user. At this point, behind the scenes, our `recently_read` function will fire and add a time stamp under the key `reading_this` (name it to your liking). This will occur each time this or any post is viewed. If a time stamp already exists for a given post, it will then update the time stamp accordingly.

Then to retrieve a list of posts with this key you would do the following in your theme files where you want those posts to display;

```
$recently_read = get_posts( 
    array(
        'posts_per_page'  => 5,       //how many posts we want to show at most
        'meta_key' => 'reading_this', //get posts by our meta key
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',    //order posts by the value stored in the key
        'order' => 'DESC'             //order posts in descending order (newest to oldest)
   )
); 

foreach ($recently_read as $read) {
    echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($read->ID) . '">'. $read->post_title .'</a>';
}
```

The above could be improved a number of ways but this will definitely get you started.

Note: This is void of any logic that determines if the post was viewed in the last X minutes. For that you can apply your own logic to the meta_key named `reading_this` and manipulate the data to your liking.